# Excel: How to select whole column except 3 or 4 cells on the top excluding merged cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I was trying to add a formula that, I want to sum up the whole columns (J:J). But I dont want to include 4 cells on the top which includes merged cell. Can anyone help me? 
Thanks

This is the picture of it: [Link the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/04gFa.png)

The column 'L' which is the 'actual Pay' is the guy. I want to select the whole column excluding the top 4 cells which include a merged cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go `=SUM(J4:J1048576)`.  Use `End` and the down key when you autofill your formula

Comment: Wow, That's amazing. Thank you very much. It worked.